# c++ error in AWS lambda?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a lambda expression that works fine with serverless on localhost.

But when deploying with lambda, I have the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "/var/lang/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /var/task/node_modules/scrypt/build/Release/scrypt.node)",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/scrypt/index.js:3:20)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/scrypt.js/node.js:1:76)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)"
  ]
```

I have not been able to find anything about this, so, is someone able to provide help about this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/),

> Native modules are similarly installed and deployed, but you’ll need
>   to build them against the Amazon Linux libraries.

So spin up an EC2 instance, build your project there, zip it up, and upload it to Lambda. It appears to make a difference which Amazon Linux AMI you use though... Probably because they are different architectures or have different library versions or something.  In my case (which was building a NodeJS project using the x509 module), the Amazon Linux 2 AMI (ami-922914f7) did not work; it resulted in an error very similar to yours.  If you try this one and it doesn't work, try re-building it on the original Amazon Linux AMI (ami-2a0f324f).  After I did that, it ran perfectly in Lambda.

Thanks to @Tommaso for the inspiration behind this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you package node dependencies on a system with a different architecture (due to some dependencies that have native code that gets compiled in your system which is different than AWS Lambda)

Run `docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-nodejs6.10` instead of `npm install` to setup the dependencies in an AWS Lambda-like environment before packaging your module before uploading it to AWS.